# Need Help : API Gateway Vs ALB

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, aws-application-load-balancer

We are using Cognito for authentication and authorization for our microservices deployed in ec2, We are currently using ALB in front of ec2 which is connected to Route-53 and then connected with API gateway, Indeed we knew this is not a good way of using both the service but was using it in a hurry. Now we have time to correct this.
What we want to do:

1. Use Cognito for authorization and authentication for our microservices deployed in ec2
2. Use auto sccaling in case of high traffic
3. Map some of the exposed API, with our custom domain url.
4. Any security related practices for both internal and external calls that we should take care!

I will be really gratefull for help from all the techies out there!

Thanks!